# Autobahn websockets Android demo crashes

Tags: android, websocket

I'm new in websockets and I've been playing with Autobahn websocket in order to make a greater project. It works great in python and js versions, but I have trouble with Android API.

I'm following the tutorials in http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/install_android_package.html and tested SimpleRpc, BroadcastClient, EchoClient with same results.

In all of them when I try to connect to the running python server through android virtual emulator, the connection close automatically, and if I reclick the connect button the application crashes. 
If I compile the application and install it in my mobile device (Android 2.2.3) it crashes when I try to connect.

What I'm doing wrong? My error may be is on linking android libraries (jackson and autobahn-lastest), but I'm following the tutorial step by step.

NOTE1: The minimum android sdk to compile examples is SDK 8.
NOTE2: When linking autobahn-latest.jar raises a duplicate manifest.xml error. I solve it by erasing manifest from jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use/build the Autobahn library from the GitHub repo sources .. the JAR is outdated .. won't work. I should probably document that / remove it.

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works perfect after using Autobahn lib source. You're doing a great job. Now I can advance to next activity in my Gantt diagram xD